# InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Input' with dtype float and shape [?,28,28,1]

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory

I am running a binary classifier between Cats and Dogs on Google Colab. I executed the script once and it executed with no errors, but when I again ran after adding Dropout layer to the network after fully connected layers, I encountered the following errors. I have also tried to restart the runtime, still the error is thrown. Then after I removed the Dropout and again restart the runtime, still the error is thrown. I have no idea what and ahy happened. Any help will be appreciated.

```
# Preprocess Data
import random
import os
import numpy as np
import pickle
import cv2
from tqdm import tqdm

img_size = 28
DIR = "train/"
images = os.listdir(DIR)

random.shuffle(images)

image_data = []
image_classification = []

with tqdm(total=len(images)) as progress_bar:
  for name in images:
    img = cv2.imread(DIR + name, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (img_size, img_size))
    img = np.array(img)

    name = name.split('.')[0]
    if name == "dog":
      classification = [1., 0.]
    else:
      classification = [0., 1.]

    image_data.append(img)
    image_classification.append(classification)
    progress_bar.update(1)

testing_size = int(0.1*(len(images)))
train_x, train_y = image_data[testing_size:], image_classification[testing_size:]
test_x, test_y = image_data[:testing_size], image_classification[:testing_size]

with open('train.data', 'wb', buffering=1000) as f:
  pickle.dump([train_x, train_y], f)

with open('test.data', 'wb', buffering=1000) as f:
  pickle.dump([test_x, test_y], f)
```

Model:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class ConvNet:
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def generate_weight_bias(self, weight, bias):
    weight = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(weight), name="Filter")
    bias = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(bias), name="Bias")
    return weight, bias

  def conv2d(self, x, filter, bias):
    return self.relu(tf.add(tf.nn.conv2d(x, filter=filter, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME'), bias))

  def max_pool(self, x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

  def relu(self, x):
    return tf.nn.relu(x)

  def dropout(self, x, keep_prob):
    return tf.nn.dropout(x, keep_prob)

  def model(self, x):
    w, b = self.generate_weight_bias([5, 5, 1, 32], [32])
    layer1_1 = self.conv2d(x, w, b)

    w, b = self.generate_weight_bias([5, 5, 32, 32], [32])
    layer1_2 = self.conv2d(layer1_1, w, b)

    layer1_3 = self.max_pool(layer1_2)

    w, b = self.generate_weight_bias([5, 5, 32, 64], [64])
    layer2_1 = self.conv2d(layer1_3, w, b)

    w, b = self.generate_weight_bias([5, 5, 64, 64], [64])
    layer2_2 = self.conv2d(layer2_1, w, b)

    layer2_3 = self.max_pool(layer2_2)

    layer3_1 = tf.reshape(layer2_3, shape=[-1, 7*7*64])

    w, b = self.generate_weight_bias([7*7*64, 1024], [1024])
    layer3_1 = self.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(layer3_1, w), b))

    w, b = self.generate_weight_bias([1024, 1024], [1024])
    layer3_2 = self.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(layer3_1, w), b))

    w, b = self.generate_weight_bias([1024, 2], [2])
    layer3_3 = (tf.add(tf.matmul(layer3_2, w), b))

    return layer3_3
```

Variables:

```
x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, 28, 28, 1], name="Input")
y = tf.placeholder('float', [None, 2], name="Label")

train_x = np.reshape(train_x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])
test_x = np.reshape(test_x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])
```

Training:

```
network = ConvNet()

total_epochs = 100
batch_size = 100

with tf.name_scope('Model'):
  prediction = tf.nn.softmax(network.model(x))

with tf.name_scope('Loss'):
  cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=prediction, labels=y))

with tf.name_scope('AdamOptimizer'):
  optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

with tf.name_scope('Accuracy'):
  accuracy = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
  accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(accuracy, tf.float32))

tf.summary.scalar("loss", cost)
tf.summary.scalar("accuracy", accuracy)

marged_summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()


with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

  summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("logs/", graph=tf.get_default_graph())

  for epoch in range(total_epochs):
    avg_cost = 0
    i = 0
    while i < len(train_x):
      start = i
      end = i + batch_size
      i = end

      epoch_x, epoch_y = np.array(train_x[start:end]), np.array(train_y[start:end])

      _, c, summary = sess.run([optimizer, cost, marged_summary_op], feed_dict={x: epoch_x, y:epoch_y})

      summary_writer.add_summary(summary, epoch*len(train_x) + int(i/batch_size))

      avg_cost += c/len(train_x)

    print("Epoch {} of {} Finished. Average Cost {}.".format(epoch+1, total_epochs, avg_cost))

  print("Accuracy: {}".format(accuracy.eval({x: test_x, y:test_y})))
```

Here is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1321     try:
-> 1322       return fn(*args)
   1323     except errors.OpError as e:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run_fn(feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1306       return self._call_tf_sessionrun(
-> 1307           options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1308 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _call_tf_sessionrun(self, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1408           self._session, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1409           run_metadata)
   1410     else:

InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Input' with dtype float and shape [?,28,28,1]
     [[Node: Input = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,28,28,1], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
     [[Node: Loss/Mean/_9 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_198_Loss/Mean", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-cd895cf45a86> in <module>()
     38       epoch_x, epoch_y = np.array(train_x[start:end]), np.array(train_y[start:end])
     39 
---> 40       _, c, summary = sess.run([optimizer, cost, marged_summary_op], feed_dict={x: epoch_x, y:epoch_y})
     41 
     42       summary_writer.add_summary(summary, epoch*len(train_x) + int(i/batch_size))

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    898     try:
    899       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 900                          run_metadata_ptr)
    901       if run_metadata:
    902         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1133     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and feed_dict_tensor):
   1134       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
-> 1135                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
   1136     else:
   1137       results = []

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1314     if handle is None:
   1315       return self._do_call(_run_fn, feeds, fetches, targets, options,
-> 1316                            run_metadata)
   1317     else:
   1318       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, handle, feeds, fetches)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1333         except KeyError:
   1334           pass
-> 1335       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1336 
   1337   def _extend_graph(self):

InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Input' with dtype float and shape [?,28,28,1]
     [[Node: Input = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,28,28,1], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
     [[Node: Loss/Mean/_9 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_198_Loss/Mean", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]

Caused by op 'Input', defined at:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 477, in start
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 177, in start
    super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 888, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 440, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 472, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 414, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 235, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 196, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 533, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2718, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2822, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2882, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-3-50881c3fb0dd>", line 1, in <module>
    x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, 28, 28, 1], name="Input")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1734, in placeholder
    return gen_array_ops.placeholder(dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 4924, in placeholder
    "Placeholder", dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3414, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1740, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Input' with dtype float and shape [?,28,28,1]
     [[Node: Input = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,28,28,1], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
     [[Node: Loss/Mean/_9 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_198_Loss/Mean", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

Comment: Based on the text of your question I think you can add `tf.reset_default_graph()` as the first line in your code and run a quick check.

Comment: Thanks! That worked!